# How can I export an web-scraping table into csv with multiple rows?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I wrote this code on Python 2.7.13, for scraping datatable from a website.

```python
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

out=open("proba.csv","rb")
data=csv.reader(out)

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

maindatatable=""
soup = make_soup("https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok")

for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    datatable=""
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        datatable=datatable+","+data.text
    maindatatable = maindatatable + "\n" + datatable[1:]

header = "Penznem,Devizanev,Egyseg,Penznemforintban"
print maindatatable

file = open(os.path.expanduser("proba.csv"),"wb")

utf16_str1 =header.encode('utf16')
utf16_str2 = maindatatable.encode('utf16')
file.write(utf16_str1)
file.write(utf16_str2)
file.close()
```

I want to export this into CSV with the next 4 rows:

"Penznem Devaizanev Egyseg Penznemforintban"

The data are separated with "," but the last two values is ONE row. (283,45)

How can I fix it?

Comment: You can use [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module in python.

Answer (score 0):

you can not avoid last coma directly but,

What you can simply do is to use another seprator i.e. ;(semicolon)
and when you open file in exel,calc select (;)semicolon as seprator and you will get result as expected!

```js
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

out=open("proba.csv","rb")
data=csv.reader(out)

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

maindatatable=""
soup = make_soup("https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok")

for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    datatable=""
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        datatable=datatable+";"+data.text
    maindatatable = maindatatable + "\n" + datatable[1:]

header = "Penznem;Devizanev;Egyseg;Penznemforintban"
print maindatatable

file = open(os.path.expanduser("proba.csv"),"wb")

utf16_str1 =header.encode('utf16')
utf16_str2 = maindatatable.encode('utf16')
file.write(utf16_str1)
file.write(utf16_str2)
file.close()
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, its a good idea! And how can i do 4 different rows? Because now this is only on row/data, separetad by ";". How can i make an arrey/block with these dataes (because later, i want to import to MYSQL database)

Comment: pretty simple use datatable.split() method first split by '\n' so you will get each row as item and then split item by ';'(semicolon) and you will get list of list contain each colmn sepratly..